# How to output XmlDocument so that element attributes are indented as well?

Tags: c#, xml, pretty-print

I want to output XmlDocument so that the attributes are indented as well.
I tried two approaches:

```
var cfgXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
cfgXmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
cfgXmlDoc.Load(cfgFilePath);
...
File.WriteAllText(cfgFilePath, cfgXmlDoc.OuterXml);
```

AND

```
var cfgXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
cfgXmlDoc.Load(cfgFilePath);
...
using (var xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(cfgFilePath, Encoding.UTF8))
{
  xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
  cfgXmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
}
```

As expected, none indent the attributes. Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

For instance, consider this piece of a XML:

```
  <dataPortalProxies thisEndpointKind="Agent">
    <dataPortalProxy isEnabled="true" name="NC Server" endpointKind="Server"
                     implementation="Shunra.Common.Csla.WcfOneWayProxy, Shunra.Common">
      <add key="AddressTemplate" value="net.msmq://{0}/private/nc_queue"/>
    </dataPortalProxy>
    <dataPortalProxy isEnabled="true" name="Peer Agent" endpointKind="Agent"
                     implementation="Shunra.Common.Csla.WcfDynamicProxy, Shunra.Common">
      <add key="AddressTemplate" value="https://{0}:7000/NCAgent/WcfPortal.svc"/>
    </dataPortalProxy>
  </dataPortalProxies>
```

Putting it through the XmlDocument yields this result:

```
  <dataPortalProxies thisEndpointKind="Agent">
    <dataPortalProxy isEnabled="true" name="NC Server" endpointKind="Server" implementation="Shunra.Common.Csla.WcfOneWayProxy, Shunra.Common">
      <add key="AddressTemplate" value="net.msmq://{0}/private/nc_queue" />
    </dataPortalProxy>
    <dataPortalProxy isEnabled="true" name="Peer Agent" endpointKind="Agent" implementation="Shunra.Common.Csla.WcfDynamicProxy, Shunra.Common">
      <add key="AddressTemplate" value="https://{0}:7000/NCAgent/WcfPortal.svc" />
    </dataPortalProxy>
  </dataPortalProxies>
```

What I want is some kind of wrap long lines for attributes, so that any attributes exceeding certain line width are indented on the following line. In short pretty printing.

Comment: You should put the programming language in the tag. I would but I don't know it...

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the XML is currently appearing versus how you want it to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use `new XmlTextWriter()` is has been deprecated since .NET 2.0.

Use `XmlWriter.Create()` instead:

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = 
    new XmlWriterSettings {Indent = true, NewLineOnAttributes = true};
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("path", settings))
{

}
```

Comment: Marked as the answer, although the output is far from being pretty. But this is the problem of the question, rather than the answer.